# Multirow bad behaviour on partial last column

Tags: tables, multirow

[Here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) is `\multirow` documentation (where I didn't find my answer), and here is my MWE (but not working as intended, illustrating the problem) :

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline      
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{my little 1rst line} \\
\hline  
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{blabla}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{blabla} \\
\hline  
    blabla & blabla & \multirow{2}{*}{whaou there is so much text here, that's embarassing, look the cell goes beyond the tabular, and even beyond the page, the worst being : you don't even get a warning for going out of the page, and i'm not even talking about the margins...} \\
\cline{1-2} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{blabla} & \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The behaviour I would like to have is no cell exceeding, iether by stretching cells or forcing newline inside cells.

Comment: Using `*` in `\multirow` causes the cell width to be the width of its contents.

Comment: And that's what I want, I want the cell to be as wide as my text is (within the page limitations), but multirow has just a bad behaviour, not only it doesn't stretch the whole tabular, but also it doesn't even respected the page limitation (see my new edited example), and doesn't even send a warning, I am considering using another method.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us what format are you looking to achive for your table, we could offer you some slternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `*` in `\multirow` causes the cell width to be the width of its contents. You can use a fixed proper length in the second argument instead:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %encodage clavier
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %encodage police
\usepackage[francais]{babel} %langue
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline      
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{my little 1rst line} \\
\hline  
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{blabla}    & \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}{blabla} \\
\hline  
    blabla & blabla & \multirow{2}{5cm}{whaou there is so much text here, that's embarassing} \\
\cline{1-2} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{blabla} & \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, depending on the actual contents of the table, your columns specifications might change (if text wrapping is required, it's better to use `p{<length>}` columns).

Comment: I see the trick is to set other cells lenght to know what to put instead of `*`

Comment: @V.B. But you won't be able to accomodate too much text (i.e., a long paragraph), since you only are spanning two rows in your `\multirow`. What kinf of table are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's ok, if i have not enough space I can still change the left "blabla" into multirows to have more rows, and have it displayed as I want (for example 5 lines on the 2 first, and 3 for the last one, or whatever else), thank you for your answer, I was confuse on how to decide the width of my multirow, and now that you said it, the answer seems obsvious, by seting other cells width.